How to combine complex dicts in list of complex dicts where key appears multiple times
I have a list of dicts, where each dict refers to a team and its assets.
e.g.
list_of_dicts = [
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "TYPEB",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEC",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
]

Where here, there are 2 dicts for team X, with different Types (TYPEA and TYPEB, then another with TYPEC), there will also be 2 dicts for Team Y, maybe 3 for team Z etc.
My desired outcome, is to have a list of dicts, where there is only 1 dict for Team X, that has Type A, B and C together.
*Have not listed desired outcome as makes for very long example. Happy to add.
Would look something like:
list_of_dicts = [
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {...},
            {,
            {
                "type": "TYPEB",
                "assets": {...},
            {,
            {
                "type": "TYPEC",
                "assets": {...},
            {,
        ],
    },
]


The second list_of_dicts is missing some close brackets.

Will fix, thanks

What have you tried?  This is not a difficult task.

Loop over one of the lists, getting the team name. Then loop over the other list, finding all the entries with the same team, and combine the types lists.

Hi @Barmar, there is only 1 list of dicts. I'm not sure how I compare the "item I'm on in the loop" to the next item in the loop, to merge them?

Hi @TimRoberts, I am a noobie, I have spent a few hours researching stack overflow for this, but I can't find anything that works for my solution, or figure out how to make them work

The question originally had two lists, I thought you wanted to merge them.

Create a dictionary whose keys are the team names. Then loop through your list of dictionaries, using this to merge the types lists for the same team.
result_dict = {}

for d in list_of_dicts:
    if d['team'] in result_dict:
        result_dict[d['team']]['types'].extend(d['types'])
    else:
        result_dict[d['team']] = d

list_of_dicts = list(result_dict.values())


Thank you so much! This works perfectly!

If you also want to merge the type assets:
input:
list_of_dicts = [
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "TYPEB",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEC",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "team": "Z",
        "description": "A description of Z",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "team": "Z",
        "description": "A description of Z",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_5_id", "name": "asset_5_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_6_id", "name": "asset_6_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_7_id", "name": "asset_7_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_8_id", "name": "asset_8_name"},
                    ],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
]

function:
from pprint import pprint as print

def group_assets_by_team_and_type(list_of_dicts: list[dict]):
    """
    Groups assets by team and type.

    Args:
        list_of_dicts (list[dict]): A list of dictionaries representing assets.

    Returns:
        list[dict]: A list of dictionaries containing assets grouped by team and type.
    """
    assets_by_team: dict[str, dict] = {}
    for item in list_of_dicts:
        team = item["team"]
        description = item["description"]
        assets_by_team.setdefault(
            team, {"team": team, "description": description, "types": {}}
        )
        for type_dict in item["types"]:
            type_name = type_dict["type"]
            assets_by_team[team]["types"].setdefault(
                type_name, {"high_value": [], "low_value": []}
            )
            assets_by_team[team]["types"][type_name]["high_value"].extend(
                type_dict["assets"]["high_value"]
            )
            assets_by_team[team]["types"][type_name]["low_value"].extend(
                type_dict["assets"]["low_value"]
            )
    return [
        {
            "team": item["team"],
            "description": item["description"],
            "types": [
                {"type": type_name, "assets": assets}
                for type_name, assets in item["types"].items()
            ],
        }
        for item in assets_by_team.values()
    ]

output = group_assets_by_team_and_type(list_of_dicts)
print(output, sort_dicts=False)

output:
output = [
    {
        "team": "X",
        "description": "A description of X",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "TYPEB",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                "type": "TYPEC",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "team": "Z",
        "description": "A description of Z",
        "types": [
            {
                "type": "TYPEA",
                "assets": {
                    "high_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_1_id", "name": "asset_1_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_2_id", "name": "asset_2_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_5_id", "name": "asset_5_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_6_id", "name": "asset_6_name"},
                    ],
                    "low_value": [
                        {"id": "asset_3_id", "name": "asset_3_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_4_id", "name": "asset_4_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_7_id", "name": "asset_7_name"},
                        {"id": "asset_8_id", "name": "asset_8_name"},
                    ],
                },
            }
        ],
    },
]

